# Batch command - adding date at the end of folder

Tags: date, batch-file

I currently run a batch command to create a folder 1 day in advanced and label it as MMDDYY.
Everything is working as intended except single digit days. Currently it named the next day folder has 12214, is it possible to have it name it as 120214?

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" 
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" 
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

:loop
  set /a DD+=1

  if %DD% gtr 31 (
    set DD=1
    set /a MM+=1

    if %MM% gtr 12 (
      set MM=1
      set /a YY+=1
      set /a YYYY+=1
    )
  )
xcopy /d:%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY% /l . .. >nul 2>&1 || goto loop

echo %DD%/%MM%/%YYYY%
mkdir "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\%mm%%dd%%yy%\"

pause
```

Comment: You should reconsider your naming convention. 2 digit years should be avoided - use 4 instead. Also, you should use yyyymmdd so that folders sort chronologically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pad again the data once the operations have been done. Also you will need some more logic to handle the month change

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Retrieve data
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a" 
    set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" 
    set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
    set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
    set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
    set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
    set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
    set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

    rem Remove padding from date elements and increase day
    set /a "y=%YYYY%", "m=100%MM% %% 100", "d=(100%DD% %% 100)+1" 
    rem Calculate month length
    set /a "ml=30+((m+m/8) %% 2)" & if %m% equ 2 set /a "ml=ml-2+(3-y %% 4)/3-(99-y %% 100)/99+(399-y %% 400)/399"
    rem Adjust day / month / year for tomorrow date
    if %d% gtr %ml% set /a "d=1", "m=(m %% 12)+1", "y+=(%m%/12)"

    rem Pad date elements and translate again to original variables
    set /a "m+=100", "d+=100"
    set "YYYY=%y%"
    set "YY=%y:~-2%"
    set "MM=%m:~-2%"
    set "DD=%d:~-2%"

    echo Tomorrow: %YYYY% / %MM% / %DD%
```

Just add the folder creation in the required format

Answer (score 0):

Batch is cumbersome with date math.  Leap years, month / year changes / etc can be a pain to deal with.  I suggest using a JScript `Date()` object, where all such conversions are handled automatically.

As follows is a batch / JScript hybrid script.  Save it with a `.bat` extension and run it as you are used to running your typical batch scripts.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end   /* JScript ignores this multiline comment

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1-3" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"') do (
    set "MM=%%I"
    set "DD=%%J"
    set "YYYY=%%K"
)

xcopy /d:%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY% /l . .. >nul 2>&1 || goto loop

echo %MM%/%DD%/%YYYY%
mkdir "%userprofile%\Desktop\%MM%%DD%%YYYY:~-2%\"

pause

goto :EOF

:: end batch portion / begin JScript */

function zeroPad(what) { return (what+'').length < 2 ? '0'+what : what; }

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

WSH.Echo([
    zeroPad(tomorrow.getMonth() + 1),
    zeroPad(tomorrow.getDate()),
    tomorrow.getFullYear()
].join(' '));
```